# Euclidean distance and dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've been reading that the Euclidean distance between two points, and the dot product of the two points, are related. Specifically, the Euclidean distance is equal to the square root of the dot product. But this doesn't work for me in practice.

For example, let's say the points are $(3, 5)$ and $(6, 9)$. The Euclidean distance is $\sqrt{(3 - 6)^2 + (5 - 9)^2}$, which is equal to $\sqrt{9 + 16}$, or $5$. However, the dot product is $(3 * 6 + 5 * 9)$, which is $63$, and the square root of this is not $5$.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: That is the case only for the magnitude of a vector $x$ in an inner product space $V$ equipped with the usual dot product. i.e $|x| = \sqrt{x\cdot x}$.

Comment: The dot product of interest is the dot product of $d=(6,9)-(3,5)$ with itself. Not the dot product between $(6,9)$ and $(3,5)$.

Answer (score 33):

Apart of the other anwers, there is indeed a relation between Euclidean distance $d(X,Y)$ and the inner product $\langle X, Y \rangle$ if the vectors $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^N$ are normalized, that is $\langle X, X \rangle=\langle Y, Y \rangle = 1$, in particular $$\frac{d(X,Y)^2}{2} = 1 - \langle X, Y \rangle.$$ This can be shown as 
$$d(X,Y)^2 = \langle X - Y, X - Y \rangle = \langle X, X \rangle + \langle Y, Y \rangle - 2 \langle X, Y \rangle = 2 (1 - \langle X, Y \rangle)$$

Comment: this is the correct answer! thanks.

Comment: Thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, the distance between $\displaystyle X = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{pmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle Y = \begin{pmatrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \end{pmatrix}$ is defined as :

$$ d(X,Y) = \Vert Y - X \Vert = \sqrt{\left\langle Y-X,Y-X \right\rangle}. $$

with $\left\langle Y-X,Y-X \right\rangle = (y_{1}-x_{1})^{2} + (y_{2}-x_{2})^{2}.$

So, if $\displaystyle X=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\displaystyle Y = \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix}$,

$$\begin{align*}
d(X,Y) &= {} \sqrt{\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle} \\[2mm]
&= \sqrt{9 + 16} \\[2mm]
&= \sqrt{25} \\[2mm]
&= 5.
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Where can I get the visual representation of of this problem? Basically, what exactly happening behind this Math? Like how the dot product is related with distance geometrically(?)

Comment: How does that answer the question...? It doesn't even mention the dot product, unless I missed smth...

Comment: The symbols $\langle a , b \rangle $ denotes the inner product of $a$ and $b$ which, in the case of Euclidean spaces, is the dot product. See here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html

Comment: @Suraj It's the distance between two points. coffeemath points out the connection between the formula and the origin, and David Curtis Bollinger helpfully added a visualization.

Answer (score 9):

The squareroot of dot product formula is for the distance to $(0,0).$ So one has to get the difference of the two vectors first, then apply.

Answer (score 1):

distance=$D=\sqrt{((|A|^2-(A\cdot B)^2)+(|B|-(A\cdot B))^2)}$

I found this geometrically like this:
[image: an image showing how I found this formula for D geometrically]

sorry for the lousy formatting, this is my first time posting here. I needed to find D in terms of norms and dot products for my linear algebra homework, as I assume most people asking this question are, and the other answers weren't helpful to me. I don't know where the original asker got that $D=\sqrt{A\cdot B}$, but hopefully the equation I found for my homework will be useful to others trying to find how D is related to the dot product.